# Oracle Sql query joining tables

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

[image]
I need output as given below

Table details provided  in attachment.

Customer record can have one (PRM or LEGAL) address type details or both (LEGAL and PRM). 
If it has both query should pick PRM details 
and ignore LEGAL record for the same customer.
If the customer has only LEGAL only record, it should pick it. Can any one help me to make query

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
WITH CustomerTable AS (
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('234567') CID FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT TO_NUMBER ('235435') CID FROM DUAL
),
CustomerAddressTable AS (
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('234567') C_CID, 'PRM' Addr_Type, 'Line 10' Addr_1, TO_NUMBER('402') Addr_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT TO_NUMBER ('234567') C_CID, 'LEGAL' Addr_Type, 'Line 2' Addr_1, TO_NUMBER('302') Addr_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT TO_NUMBER ('235435') C_CID, 'LEGAL' Addr_Type, 'Line 1' Addr_1, TO_NUMBER('502') Addr_2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CustomerTable.CID, CustomerAddressSubset.Addr_1, CustomerAddressSubset.Addr_2 FROM
CustomerTable
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT CustomerAddressTable.* FROM CustomerAddressTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT C_CID, Max(Addr_Type) Addr_Type FROM CustomerAddressTable GROUP BY C_CID) t
ON CustomerAddressTable.C_CID = t.C_CID AND CustomerAddressTable.Addr_type = t.Addr_type
) CustomerAddressSubset
ON CustomerTable.CID = CustomerAddressSubset.C_CID
```

Using Max(AddrType) selects PRM above LEGAL because PRM occurs later in the alphabet.

The first left join allows you to use any other fields you happen to have in CustomerTable: your example shows only the CID but I assume you would have others.

The inline view CustomerAddressSubset will contain only one address type for each customer ID C_CID in the CustomerAddressTable.